# This C program wont compile/run?

Tags: c

This program won't compile on Code::Blocks. I tried changing different values within it but no matter what I do it wont compile. Can anyone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI = 3.141597
#define WAVELENGTH 70
#define PERIOD .1

int main()
{
    float i,s,x;
    i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=PI;i+=PERIOD)
    {
        s = sin(i);
        for (x=0;x<s*WAVELENGTH;x++)
        {
            putchar('*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
In function 'main'
Line | 12 | error: expected expression before '=' token
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Comment: If there is a compilation error, please add it to your question (copy-paste from your compilation environment)

Comment: use `#define PI 3.141597` as you are using for `WAVELENGTH`

Comment: Its working fine, i checked in online C Compiler.

Comment: as you are using `int` return type. try `return 0` in the end

Comment: the problem was #define PI = 3.141597, but i figured it out thank you all :)

Comment: pi is 3.141592653..., so you should use `#define PI 3.141593`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI  3.141597
#define WAVELENGTH 70
#define PERIOD .1

int main()
{
    float i,s,x;
    i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=PI;i+=PERIOD)
    {
        s = sin(i);
        for (x=0;x<s*WAVELENGTH;x++)
        {
            putchar('*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `=` from macro `#define PI = 3.141597`. It should

```
#define PI 3.141597
```

Comment: thank you i figured it out was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As u didn't mentioned whats the error. I found two errors in your code

```
1. the "= " in #define PI = 3.141597 so remove = sign
and
2. return type in main() finction.  add return 0; in the end
```

Comment: compilers implicitly add `return 0;` at the end of the main function. So this is not an error

Comment: i am using  **Turbo C**, and it always ask me to add return

Comment: yeah i agree nothing was wrong except an = in #define!

Comment: okay cool. any way your problem is solved.

Comment: you should not use an 26 years old compiler.